# Installing Git in Ubuntu using Python script

Tags: python, git, ubuntu, subprocess

I'm trying to write a script which checks for prerequisite software in Ubuntu and if not installed, goes ahead and installs it.

I'm a newbie to Python and I understand that Python's `subprocess` module can be used to achieve this goal.

I have written this below sample code but not sure why it is failing.

```
import subprocess
c = subprocess.Popen(['sudo','apt-get','install','git'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
grep_stdout = c.communicate(input='root')[0]
print(grep_stdout)
```

When I run this program, i get the following error...

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

Am i missing something here?

Comment: Why are you writing this script in Python? Ubuntu's package management works perfectly well as is.

Comment: If your program is dependent on Git, I'd advocate just letting it fail gracefully when Git's not present, and leave it up to the user to install/compile Git as they wish.

Comment: There are significant amount of pre-requisite . I just thought asking user to  install all of them would be a pain in the neck. so just thought of writing a function which will test the software and if something not installed will go ahead and install for him

Comment: A reasonable thought process. @Burhan's answer is fantastic, and covers all the main options you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There are significant amount of pre-requisite . I just thought asking
>   user to install all of them would be a pain in the neck. so just
>   thought of writing a function which will test the software and if
>   something not installed will go ahead and install for him

There are a few approaches to this:

1. Check if software is there, if it isn't exit the program with a message listing the missing components to be installed.
2. Provide a list of software that needs to be installed in `README` or documentation.
3. Create a [debian package](http://wiki.debian.org/CreateDummyPackage) listing the dependencies required; and have the user install this with their preferred method.

If your program *must* install the software itself (does it really have to?), then instruct the user to run your script with elevated privileges. In your documentation, ask them to run it as `root`.

By the way `sudo` may not be installed on all systems.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import subprocess

c = subprocess.Popen(['sudo','yum','install','git','-y'], 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
grep_stdout = c.communicate(input='root')[0]

print(grep_stdout)
```

Comment: install git on centos or RHEL using python

Comment: Please if you are typing a code codeify it by pressing Ctrl+K. And also explain your answer so that others can understand it.